# Search Bar gets clipped depending on the width of website being odd/even

Tags: bug, design

The width of the website is affecting the user profile part of the topbar overlapping the edge of the search bar;

- when the width of the webpage is even on the browser, e.g. `1000px`

  [image]
- when the width is odd, e.g. `1001px`;

  [image]

It is happening on my Win10 latest Google Chrome.

Comment: Although I don't suggest you delete this question, because you've included some good debugging information that isn't mentioned in the the other duplicate linked to that one.